# Redirect to default domain in Business Catalyst

Tags: redirect, business-catalyst

I have a Business Catalyst site that needs the following domains redirected to the default domain.
www.membersalliance.com.au/
www.membersalliance.com.au/index.aspx

The default domain is www.membersalliance.com.au

We have been told that these three pages are seen by google as separate content and we want to consolidate them to all go to the default domain.

I have spoken to adobe support and they said that:
‪

> Redirecting to another page can be done, there's no issue with that. But what we're looking for here is to not have any other postfix with the domain name. When a page is set to be the starting page, there is an automatic functionality that the postfix/name of the page is removed, but that is not the case with other pages.‪So, they would still show the name of the page, even if you redirect it to the home page (starting page set for your domain).‬

So, I can redirect to www.membersalliance.com.au/home.html but is this seen by google as a separate page to www.membersalliance.com.au?

Answer (score 1):

If you re-direct a page using 301 redirects (which is how BC re-directs a page if you use re-directs) Google will only see the one page, not multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google Webmaster Tools help on "canonical" URLs.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

In your case, add to page head:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.membersalliance.com.au"/>
```

This will tell Google to treat all variants of homepage to be recorded against a single domain.